# Comparison of Java System Properties and Context Parameters

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

When running an application in a servlet container like tomcat I have multiple ways of passing custom configuration to the application:

- System Properties (passed as -D parameter on startup)
- Context Parameters (web.xml or context.xml)
- Environmental Variables (os-wide)

While I feel confident about the pros and cons of environmental variables, I fail to see the difference, pros and cons of System Properties and context parameters. Both may be easily retrieved and set within the application. So what's the right to exist for context parameters? Why not simply use System Properties for everything?

Comment: Because some of them might be similar in all machines and you don't want to force the user to pass them. You just set them in the xml and change them according to the context (not the system/machine you are running at). Environment are good but they are shared for all java applications. System properties are something in between. For example if you have 3 java apps and you want to run them with different memory setting - you use system properties.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov You're talking about the context.xml within the webapp (META-INF/context.xml), right? So this is like a default value defined by the webapp, which may be overriden by a custom System Property. So isn't still still quite similar? Sorry, but I still fail to see the use case / advantage of the context parameters, which can't be achieved with System Properties :(

Comment: The idea here is that the developer does not neccesarily have the control over the Java System Properties of the container. Especially in the past there were separate teams developing the apps on one hand and providing/ running the JEE container infrastructure on the other. It was also quite common to run multiple apps in one container. In such scenario the provide / run team was not ready to change system properties of the whole container.  There also might be a software provider shipping a war file who cannot / will not be prescribing the system environment for customer's container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what's the right to exist for context parameters? Why not simply use System Properties for everything?

So that different applications can have different values.

You may want to set the configuration file location for an application. Say,

```
-Dconfig.file=/etc/myapp/config.cfg
```

If you want to have multiple copies of the same application running at once, you might want to use `/etc/myapp/config1.cfg` and `/etc/myapp/config2.cfg`, etc.

If you are using a system property, you can only have one value for the property. With context parameters, you can have a value that is distinct for each application. In fact, each context: it could be the same application deployed multiple times under different configurations.

There is another reason, but this one is more subtle. Changing system properties is ... problematic. Generally speaking, Java components read their configuration when they come into service and therefore changing the values of those system properties after the fact generally has no effect. Try disabling `java.awt.headless` after it's been set, for example.

If you wanted to change the value of `config.file`, you'd have to restart your web application, but you'd also have to change that value within the running JVM. That's an awkward operation. (I suppose your application might be able to do that, but why bother when there are better ways to accomplish your objective?).

The alternative, which makes much more sense to me, is to alter the value of the context-parameter and redeploy the web application. Again, this does not interfere with any other application running within the same container and also achieves the goal of changing the configuration for that application.

Comment: This is probably the best explanation for deciding between system property vs context param.